# Pass/set variables for a modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a notes/comment system for a project at work.
Currently, clicking either "new" or "reply" (both links, but I could easily change them to buttons) brings up a bootstrap modal in which the user can enter their comment/reply.
I need to be able to set whether the comment is new, or a reply to someone else's, which I would like do by setting an int corresponding to the id of the comment being responded to (0 for a new comment).

It seems like I should be able to use the OnClick event to set the variable I need, but said event doesn't seem to fire when opening the modal.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">Add a comment</div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <label><small>Author: </small><%:this.Author %></label><br />
       <label><small>Date: </small>Date</label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="text_M_NOTE" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="10em" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:button runat="server"  class="NotePopupButton" onclick="Post_Click" Text="Save" />
        <asp:button runat="server" class="NotePopupButton" data-dismiss="modal" Text="Cancel" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For triggering the modal, I've tried using asp LinkButton;

```
<asp:LinkButton data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' runat="server" OnClick="New_Click">New comment...</asp:LinkButton>
```

Regular hyperlink;

```
<a href="#" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' runat="server"
```

Hyperlink with onserverlick instead of onclick...

```
<a href="#" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' runat="server" onserverclick ="New_Click">New comment...</a>
```

Nothing yet has worked. The code behind is simply

```
protected void New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NoteParent = "0"; // 0 Indicates a new comment
}
```

and/or

```
protected void Reply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NoteParent = "12"; // Indicates a reply to comment #12
}
```

I should point out that the modal opens and saves the comment just fine, it just won't include the `NoteParent` variable; it shows up as null.

I'm guessing that whatever magic Bootstrap is doing behind the scenes is consuming the event before my code behind can do its thing. How do you get around that?

Comment: Where is `NoteParent` defined?

Comment: onserverlick should be onserverclick.  And shouldn't you handle the new/reply in Post_Click not New_Click?

Comment: @KSib `NoteParent` is defined at the top of the page class. It's not actually necessary. I could set a hidden textfield with, and then pull from there when I save the note.

Comment: @SQLDBA `New_Click()`(or `Reply_Click()`) opens the modal and _ideally_ sets the variable (`New_Click()` would set it to 0, `Reply_Click()` would set it to 12 or whatever. I suppose I had it backwards in my example). `Post_Click()` is where everything is written out to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to make server calls, if you need to set a variable before opening the modal, just remove the `data-toggle` attribute and create a JavaScript function to handle the button click, inside the function check if this is a new comment or a reply by setting a JavaScript variable or hidden field value, then show the modal dialog pragmatically

Comment: Found a solution in a hybrid between this and my strange aversion to JavaScript; removed `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes from the link, then changed the onClick to include `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "mShow", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);` What's curious now, though, is that just setting the varibale (defined within the class) didn't work. Using a session variable or a global class did.

Comment: It seems using a hidden field instead of a variable also works. Strange.

Regardless, thanks for the help.